# XML Linq Reading multiple nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to extract data from a wordpress blog xml feed, this is the format of the xml: http://brockallen.com/category/asp-net/feed/

```
var xElements = XElement.Parse(ResponseText);
var blogs = (from temp in xElements.Elements()
             select new 
             {
                 Title = temp.Element("item").Element("title").Value,
                 URL = temp.Element("item").Element("link").Value,
                 Image = temp.Element("item").Element("media:content").Value
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I get them all, and store them in to an object?

Error on `media:content` is saying The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.`

When I remove that line, it only gets one, when there are more, even after removing `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: You're explicitly calling `FirstOrDefault`. If you don't just want the first item, don't do that :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmm, I took that out and it works, but still only returns 1, when there's more

Comment: The `blogs` variable has only `[0]` = 1 result in Results View

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy please review  http://brockallen.com/category/asp-net/feed/ for an example

Comment: updated the answer with a sample of similar structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...updated with namespace for querying `content` element

```
    // var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"<your xml location>");
    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse("<your xml string>");
    XNamespace ns = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";

    var blogs = (from temp in xDoc.Descendants().Elements("item")
                 select new
                 {
                     Title = temp.Element("title").Value,
                     URL = temp.Element("link").Value,
                     Image = temp.Element(ns + "content").Value
                 });
```

Comment: this way you can only get the first media item for each title, while there are a lot of them in your document

Comment: to get all `content` elements, just use `Image = temp.Elements(ns + "content")` or if only image urls are needed then - `Image = temp.Elements(ns + "content").Attributes("url")`

Answer (score 2):

Your are working on the wrong level of the document.
Also you need an namespace.

```
  XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
  var items =
  from channelElement in XElement.Parse(ResponseText).Element("channel").Elements("item")
  select new {
    Title = channelElement.Element("title").Value,
    Url = channelElement.Element("link").Value,
    MediaItems = (
        from mediaItemElement in channelElement.Elements(media + "content")
        select new {
            url = mediaItemElement.Attribute("url").Value,
            medium = mediaItemElement.Attribute("medium").Value
            }
        ).ToList()
  };
```

Comment: Yes, this works great. Thanks.. Except its throwing an error when I try to get `media:content` node: `The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.`

Comment: @ZeeTee: That's because it's using a *namespace* with an alias of `media`. Look up using namespaces in LINQ to XML.

Comment: Is there a way to easily plug it in your code or is it a larger task than your code

Comment: updated the answer so you are able to show media:content as a list